# I am trying to run 2 statements

Tags: oracle10g

truncate table abc;

Insert into table abc;
truncate table xyz;

these are large database and takes large time to truncate, before truncate only the data us been getting inserted into database

Comment: Before data is been truncated the insert statement is running, how to resolve?

Comment: Got the following error   ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified

Comment: The truncate will wait until it can get an exclusive lock on the object. Look for any other sessions that are trying to do anything with that table.